# Rewrite rule url character replace

Tags: .htaccess, replace, url-rewriting, character

How can i replace + to - in my url. What code shoud I add in my htacces to get rid of + and replace it with a minus.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com\/Download\/free\/%2.html? [R,L,NE]
```

If i type a search that contain spaces, every space become + and i want -.

Comment: Where does `+` appear in the URL? And why do you have rewrite rules that doesn't address your problem at all?

Comment: http://mysite.com/Download/free/bla+bla+bla.html Because this is what i have in my .htacces file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that the **bla+bla+bla** part of the URL: `http://mysite.com/Download/free/bla+bla+bla.html` originated from the query string `search=`'s value. Depending on what other rules you may have, you can go about this in 2 different ways. You can either remove all of the spaces from the query string first, before it's redirected to the .html file. Or you can rewrite the query string into the URI, then remove the spaces before *redirecting*. It'll be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(.*?)(\+|%20)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /?search=%1-%3 [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(\+|%20)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com\/Download\/free\/%1.html? [R,L,NE]
```

Note that in your htaccess you have the **%2** back reference, which doesn't seem to reference anything.

Or rewrite to URI first, then redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ /Download\/free\/%1.html? [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\ )
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1-$2 [L]
```

Comment: First option worked for me. I searched for a good answer on this issue, 1 month. Thanks alot.